# Filter in Join instead of Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, filter

I'm adapting queries that hard code a filter of inclusion values in the join. When I Inner Join a table of values instead of hardcoding the values, I get more records back.  Does anyone have any insight why?

The original query hardcodes the inclusion values in the inner join and it comes back with 1600 records

```
SELECT DISTINCT dat.HLV_ID, dat.CUR_VALUE_DATETIME, sde.CONCEPT_ID
FROM SMRTDTA_ELEM_DATA dat
INNER JOIN CLARITY_CONCEPT sde ON dat.ELEMENT_ID = sde.CONCEPT_ID
    AND sde.CONCEPT_ID IN ('EPIC#....','EPIC#.....','EPIC#.....')
```

Inner Joining a list of inclusion values into a temp table brings back more results

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LOOKUPCODES') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #LOOKUPCODES;
SELECT sde.CONCEPT_ID  code_id, 'clarity_eap.proc_id' as code_id_field 
INTO #LOOKUPCODES
FROM CLARITY_CONCEPT sde
WHERE sde.CONCEPT_ID IN ('EPIC#....','EPIC#.....','EPIC#.....')

SELECT DISTINCT  dat.HLV_ID, dat.CUR_VALUE_DATETIME , sde.CONCEPT_ID
FROM SMRTDTA_ELEM_DATA dat
INNER JOIN CLARITY_CONCEPT sde ON dat.ELEMENT_ID = sde.CONCEPT_ID
INNER JOIN #LOOKUPCODES l on l.code_id = sde.CONCEPT_ID
```

Comment: If you identify some of the additional results which are coming back you should be able to then identify the logic which is pulling them back.

Comment: @GSerg Shouldn't `DISTINCT` eliminate those duplicates?

Comment: @JeannieH 1) Is this the actual query? 2) Are you certain the list for `concept_id` values is absolutely identical between the 2?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]